# Calling instance methods?

Tags: objective-c

I am a bit confused now why sometimes we call an instance method this way:

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

double seconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];

and sometimes we do it this way:

NSDate *later = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:100000];

and why it gives me error if I used the second one this way:

double later = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:100000];

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDates and doubles are different things. `double later = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:100000];` gives an error because the method `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` returns an NSDate and not a double, as you declared it.

In contrast to this, the method `timeIntervalSince1970` returns an NSTimeInterval (the time difference in seconds), which is the same as a double.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer...
How would I know what something returns in the future if I didn't made it ?